# Android, Returning to original state if selected "NO" on "Do you want to save?"

Tags: android, button, back

I'm making a notepad for my project and I'd like to know how I can not save and go back to unedited (note before save) state.

For example, by clicking on the back button, a message prompts me to ask if I want to save. If I press "NO" I can go back to the main page WITHOUT saving the edited note.

here's my code for the back button.

```
public void onBackPressed(){            
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Confirm");                
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to save?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast saved = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Note
                              Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                saved.show();
                saveState();
                finish();
                dialog.dismiss();                       
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show()
}
```

Can anyone advise me what should be done on the "NO" button? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that this is a computer. It won't do anything unless you tell it to. So unless you explicitly are telling it to save, it won't. So all you have to do is not tell it to. If all you want to do is not save, then just don't call your save method.

If you are trying to go back to the previous page without saving then make sure that your save method isn't being called at any other point in the activity (for example as the user is typing or editing). When the user presses "NO", I would recommend just doing `dialog.dismiss()` and then calling the super method `super.onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

remove `finish();` from your `setNegativeButton` click and it will stay on that screen without exiting the application. and please call `super.onBackPressed();`